# Digital twin: App asking for Admin Approval when I'm trying to access application via the browser

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm doing a POC on Azure digital twin & stuck at the authentication level where i'm getting following error in the browser window.[image]

My understanding here is that i am the one who has created the application so i should be the admin of the application. Now with all the details, i am trying to access then who is the another admin who supposed to grant me access or is there someting i'm missing in the app permissions section??

My reference to documents are:
https://medium.com/agilix/getting-started-with-windows-azure-ad-authentication-using-postman-e37a185b642d

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-facilities-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to login with a user that has **global admin** rights and Grant the consent for all users:
[Grant consent for all users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YAUt.png)